# SQL create counter column for duplicate

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, amazon-athena, dbvisualizer

I am trying to create a count column when the same customer contacts regarding an item ("attached_to col" below).

Attempt below shows the total count, but is not a counter. I would like it to show as a counter by date as per screenshot

```
select
    concat(Customer,'-',attached_to) as MergedID,
    Customer,
    record,
    purchasedate,
    attached_to,
    COUNT(MergedID) OVER (PARTITION BY MergedID) AS Count
from 
    table 1
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

nvm found answer, all good.

```
select
concat(Customer,'-',attached_to) as MergedID,
Customer,
record,
purchasedate,
attached_to,
row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY MergedID order by purchase date) AS Count
from table 1
```